# Css :hover for another elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is a part of my html structure.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo1.png" alt="SQM Digital Signage">
    </div>
    <div class="tx">
      <h2>Instalacja multimedialna</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to make :hover for my `.logo` div who will work same on `h2` element with scale, like this one.

```
.logo img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
}
```

I can't find any solution in CSS in gogole

Comment: So, you are trying to scale `.logo` and your `h2` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code checks if you are hovering over `.logo` instead. This way, you can animate both at the same time.

```css
.logo:hover > img, .logo:hover + .tx {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo1.png" alt="SQM Digital Signage">
        </div>
        <div class="tx">
            <h2>Instalacja multimedialna</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like said in the comments, above wouldn't work if you hover `<h2>`.
Instead we can check for hovering `.logo` and animate it's children.

```css
.img:hover > .logo, .img:hover > .tx {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(54px);
    transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo1.png" alt="SQM Digital Signage">
        </div>
        <div class="tx">
            <h2>Instalacja multimedialna</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't scale, when hovered over `<h2>`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change the HTML structure. You'll need a common container to the `<img>` and `<h2>`.

When `hover` on the container, you can change the styles of it's descendant elements.

HTML:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.logo {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
}
/* On hover of image change the styles of image and h2 */

.logo:hover img,
.logo:hover h2 {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="logo tx">
      <img src="logo1.png" alt="SQM Digital Signage">
      <h2>Instalacja multimedialna</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made rwd for both divs and it will be a lot of changes...
Maybe JavaScript will be better for this?

Comment: @Quzziy Yes, if you want to keep both the `<div>` separate, you'll need javascript

Comment: @Quzziy A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32263068/2025923. This may help you, if you want to do this using jQuery